# Tar is not working in termux while extracting .tar.gz file

Tags: android, terminal

I have success fully installed Ubuntu proot in termux (Android App) but I m trying to reinstall Ubuntu proot amd I don't know how and why ....tar is giving error while extracting Ubuntu.tar.gz file.
Error is :-

```
tar: bin/rbash: Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx: No such file or directory tar: bin/ypdomainname: Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx: No such file or directory
```

I m using android v5.1.1 aarch64, plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing tar with bsdtar